# Any idea for knowing if the certain percent of chance triggers

Tags: php

I have a game development project and I have specific character one of the skill of the character is that it has a 10% chance of doubling its attack.

Question: How can I trigger it?

Comment: Huh? No idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry I have a bad english. I have a game project and the situation is example the "soldier" has a 10% chance making his attack times two so if his normal attack is 100 there will be a 10% chance to make it 200 how can I do this?

Comment: It's not the english that is the problem it is the issue description. Please update your question with the above comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doubleHit($percentChance = 30)
{
    if (mt_rand(1,100) <= $percentChance) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump(doubleHit(35)); // will return either true / false
```

Note that this is only pseudorandom. Also note that this [is faster / better](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php) than `rand()`.

Comment: can I change the $percentChance to any value? like from 1%-100%?

Comment: Sure no problem. Just pass it a different integer and it will work.

Comment: Just an example percentage of a double hit. In your example from your question it would be 10.

Answer (score 3):

I hope i understand ure question:

```
<?php
$random = rand(1,10);
if(($random == 1) || ($random == 2) || ($random == 3))
    $value += $value;
?>
```

Here you have a 30% chance to hit 1, 2 or 3.. and if its hit then your value gets doubled.

**Ok now for your Update u just need a 10% chance? But okay:**

```
<?php
$random = rand(1,10);
if($random == 1)
    $value += $value;
?>
```

Comment: And if the percent is 90% he will probably have to check if(($random == 1) || ($random == 2) || ($random == 3) || ($random == 4) || ($random == 5) || ($random == 6) || ($random == 7) || ($random == 8) || ($random == 9)) ?

Comment: I have ansered that one, Braned Washed :)

Answer (score 0):

For example this code will double the value theoretically one in three times? It's hard for me to understand you.

```
$value = 200;
if (rand(1,3)===1) {
   $value*=2;
}
```

Or maybe this, for percents:

```
$value = 200;
$percent = 30;
$chance = rand(1, 100);
if ($chance <= $percent) {
    $value *= 2;
}
```

Comment: Why downvote? At least give me some feedback, just trying to help.

Comment: youre chance is 33,333% and not 30% I think